# Retrieve in which state of the lifecycle's controller we are

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle, viewdidload

Imagine there is a method in my MVC Controller who can be called multiple time during different time of is life.

Is there a way to retrieve, and print out enventually, in wich state is this Controller ?

It's maybe a short and/or dumb question, but with this indication it'll be easier to know if this method is called at a wrong or good time.

Comment: What are the differerent "states" you'd be looking for?

Comment: Are you asking about the states of lifecycle of ViewController?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry if this wasn't clear  like viewDidLoad, willLoad, willDesappear, ...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about exactly this: [managing Application LifeCycle as you move through an App](http://robbroadwell.com/blog/swift/lifecycle-viewcontroller/).

I'd suggest you subclass `UIViewController` with this `LifeCycleViewController`, and then for every VC in the App subclass the `LifeCycleViewController`. That way as you move around, in the logs you'll get:

```
'RootView willAppear'

'RootView didLoad'
```

etc.